# Is this surname Maizen?

Tags: 19th-century, palaeography, marriage-records, austria, german-language

I've got a marriage record from 1837 written in German and wish to determine the maiden name of the bride's mother underlined in red:
[image]

I think it says Maria Maizen, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Looks like a g to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure, it is Maizen.

g looks different than z, see other words containing g, such as "Durch bezirksobrigkeitliche Bewilligung" in the column "Urkunden" on the same page.

Comment: I believe it could be ß instead of z. So it could be Maissen surname and the such one exists

Comment: @GeorgeGaál But is Maissen a Slovenian surname?

Comment: @WilliamKF I have no idea about it. The only thing I know that Germans were distributed among large territory so it is not uncommon, for example, to find German surname in Ukraine or Romania.